# UISlider with different segmentation levels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uislider

I'd like to create a range slider that has different sensitivity levels.
It needs to act differently depending on the specific part in the range the user has chosen.
i.e. - if my slider's range is 1-100,000, then setting the range at lower values will jump by 1, and setting the range at the higher values will jump by 100.

eBay implemented this kind of slider in their website (notice the price range slider on the left): http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_FS=0&_sacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=car&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=490&_udhi=21%2C000%2C000

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the slider's range to be 0 - 5. Then calculate the desired value as `10 ^ sliderValue`. This basically gives you a logarithmic scale.

If you want discrete, but different linear ranges, then the answer by kabram is probably more what you want.

Update:

Set the slider's range from 0.0 to 5.0. As the slider's value changes, the calculated value becomes:

```
double newValue = pow(10, slider.value);
```

where `slider` is the `UISlider`. `pow` is a standard C math function. This gives you the following:

```
slider.value newValue
     0.0          1.0
     1.0         10.0
     2.0        100.0
     3.0       1000.0
     4.0      10000.0
     5.0     100000.0
```

Comment: can you please elaborate that? I didn't get the calculation you suggested

Answer (score 3):

Since the slider is not showing the associated value, why don't you simply add an action outlet to the value-change event and compute the appropriate jumps.

So for e.g., set the slider's range to 1 to 100. Let's assume you are showing the computed range using a label.

Label's value will then be:

```
if slider.value < 10, then value = range
else if slider.value < 20 then value = 10 + (slider.value - 10) * 2 // increments of 2
else if slider.value < 50 then value = 10 + 10 * 2 + (slider.value - 20) * 5 // increments of 5
```

...

you get the idea?